# Jenkins error: Error fetching remote repo

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to create a build in Jenkins.
I have created a mercurial installation in Manage Jenkins -> Global tools configuration.

(I CAN clone the repo in command line with the same user)

But I have this error in the console output:

> ```
> timeout=10
> ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
> hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/libpath.git
>   at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:909)
>   at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1131)
>   at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1167)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:125)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMSourceRetriever.lambda$doRetrieve$1(SCMSourceRetriever.java:157)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMSourceRetriever.retrySCMOperation(SCMSourceRetriever.java:107)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMSourceRetriever.doRetrieve(SCMSourceRetriever.java:156)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMSourceRetriever.retrieve(SCMSourceRetriever.java:96)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryAdder.retrieve(LibraryAdder.java:157)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryStep$Execution.run(LibraryStep.java:207)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryStep$Execution.run(LibraryStep.java:156)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
>   at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:359)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/libpath.git
> ```
>
> +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master" returned status code 128:
>       stdout: 
>       stderr: error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/libpath/refs
>
> ```
> fatal: HTTP request failed
>
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2430)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2044)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:81)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:569)
>   at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:907)
>   ... 18 more
> ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
> [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
>
> GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result
>
> ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting
> Finished: FAILURE
> ```

Here is my job config:
[Job config image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgt7T.png)

And there are some libraries defined too:
[libraries image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikZ2x.png)

Comment: Hi, it looks that the user you have stored in jenkins doesn't have access rights on that specific github repository. However , you should post some printscreens with your project configuration if you need more help. See here if you can find any helpful information: https://www.jenkins.io/solutions/github/

Comment: i added some images, do you need more information? i am loging to jenkins with LDAP, but i am using github credentials tu build the job.

Comment: On one hand you say "I can clone the repo in [the] command line with the same user" and later on you say "if I try to clone the repo by command line I have a forbidden error 403". Could you please explain?

Comment: ups sorry @MrMister I fix the question. i can i can. i can clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i fix this error.
The git version which was installed in jenkins was too old.
I have updated the version and now the error was fixed.

Please, if you have this error, just check your GIT version.